# How to Create Startup Page Custom module .cshtml in Orchard

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I am using Orchard 1.7 and I want to make start page from my custom module.

I've created a module with name MYMODULE and under it's view folder I have *.cshtml with name Index. I want to set Index page as a startup page of my site. It means first page will be Index.cshtml from MYMODULE.

Is it Possible? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable the aliasUI feature in Modules section

Add a blank route that points to /MyModule/MyController and it should work. May have to delete the current homepage url. And maybe it isn't blank but a "/". I cant remember ^_^

EDIT:

Check this link out: http://davidhayden.com/blog/modifying-orchard-permalinks-after-publishing-content-items Now if you follow the instructions to modify urls, you will see an alias called

> /

This will probably link to your Welcome to Orchard page route, ie. /Contents/Item/Display/12 or something. Edit this route to point at your custom page.

Comment: hi  Hazza, i am beginner with orchard and not have enough knowledge  about this  . so as a beginner can't understand your commands. can you explain it briefly or do you have any snapshot for this ? please help me

Answer (score 0):

i solve this problem .please follow these steps:-

1. Login with Admin  and open dashboard page.
2. Enable Aliases Module.
3. Click on Aliases Link  left on dashboard page.
4. Edit  first Aliase (top most) change only RoutePath  write your module name

/controllername(Mymodule/home)

after that it will be your startup