# how to change the homepage to a custom page in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms

I have a custom view page created, how can I make this page the home page?

I tried going into Orchard.Alias, but didn't figure out the way to fix this. Can you please let me know an easy solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable the feature Alias UI and go to that. The homepage route is blank (or possibly a single slash, I forget). So point your custom route (from a controller I assume) to that homepage url in the Alias UI.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But when i changed the Alias Path on Dashboard,i'm now getting a route error saying that "http://localhost:XXXXX/OrchardLocal couldnot be found",i understand that since we have changed the path now,we should also change the path which it takes when we run the application.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you redirecting to a controller action? Are you sure that that works fine?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19550109/1037489 Check this answer, it is a bit more detailed :)

Answer (score 0):

This could be done in two ways:

1. Enable Autoroute module, then edit you page and set it as homepage. ( can be changed later from cms - but it is plain html)
2. In the current theme, in views folder create a new file named Content-Homepage.cshtml and drop your code there( hardcoded - but can make use of Controllers)

Answer (score 0):

To change default url, you need to enable **Alias UI** module,then go to alias module, you will find an alias with a **slash** then click on edit. Do not write write anything in **alias path**, you need to change in **Route Path**. There you need to write the path you need to call when the site runs. You need to start from module name to the action method you want to call.
e.g. Users/Account/LogOn
Here **Users** is the module name, **Account** is the controller name and **LogOn** is the action name I have called.